# How to prep jicama - is peeling necessary?

Tags: vegetables, peeling

I recently grabbed some jicama from the store on a whim, and I used to make some really delicious slaw.  However in the course of prepping it, I sent a whole lot to the trashcan during the peeling process.  Is the waxy rind of jicama a add-on like the waxy coat on apples? Is the rind edible at all? Can it be cooked rind-on like a potato and served that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jicama does have a tough thick skin that is usually always removed.  As you know from your experience there are two layers...the outer dark papery skin and then the tough dark yellow fibrous portion.

The best way I've found (with least amount of frustration) is to peel it the same as you would a pineapple:  Trim off both ends and then cutting from top to bottom following the countours of the vegetable to cut just under the skin.

I've never seen or heard of anyone using it skin-on.

Comment: Right. I know there is an urge not to waste vegetables, but remind yourself: you aren't wasting it when you get rid of the bad tasting part so you can enjoy the good.

Answer (score 1):

The skin is poisonous. Remove and throw out.